# posts_per_page stop working after wordpress update from 4.2.1 to 4.6.1

Tags: pagination

My code for displaying custom post type stop working, when I updated WordPress version from 4.2.1 to 4.6.1.

Here's my code:

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'seller','posts_per_page' => 3,'orderby' => 'ID');     
$the_get_deals = new WP_Query( $args );
$count = 0; 
if ( $the_get_deals->have_posts() ) {
echo '<ul class="deal_by_cat" id="top_deals">';
while ($the_get_deals->have_posts()) : $the_get_deals->the_post();
if($count==2){$last_deal ='last';}else{$last_deal='';}
echo '<li class="top_active_deal '.$last_deal.'">' ;
echo '<p class="top_deal_text"><a href="'.site_url().'/google-analytics/'. get_the_ID().'" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">'.get_the_title().'</a></p><hr /></li>';
$count++;
endwhile;
echo '</ul>';
}
```

**The above code is giving me 81 post, as it should only show 3 post.**

Important thing to notic here that this code is working fine with post, page and another custom post type. I means if I change the query to 'post_type' => 'post' or 'post_type' => 'page', it working fine.
Anyone please help me with the right solution.

Comment: Has the way you register the post type changed?

Comment: "stop working" so what happens now actually? this should work right now.

Comment: I didn't changes anything in this particular post type from months. It was working fine before wordpress update. I updated the wordpress version last week and I am having this issue now.

Comment: Please define "not working". This could mean a whole array things such as you are only getting 2 back or none at all.

In relevance to your question, it could be that the post type has become unregistered for whatever reason. Try registering another post type and test with above code. This will help narrow it down to whether it is something to do with that post type or custom post types as a whole.

Comment: If the post type unregistered, it shouldn't show in WordPress admin. But its I can see it in the admin, also the above code I mentioned giving me result , but not as I expected. I have 1984 post available in that particular post type and the above query giving me 81 post. I suppose to show only 3 post. Sorry, I didn't mentioned it in my question.

Comment: To narrow it down, I think it would be useful to see the actual query with `print_r( $the_get_deals );` to see what the SQL actually looks like and stuff like this.

Comment: Its giving me 81 WP_Post Object.

Comment: Try only querying for published posts

Comment: I already tried this, same result.